# ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_2: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5 in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to use a function to add layers to a very deep CNN using keras. Here is my function:

```
def add_layer(input_shape, kernel_size, filters, count):
    x = Conv2D(filters, (kernel_size, kernel_size), padding = 'same', activation= None)(Input(input_shape))
    x = BatchNormalization()(x) 
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Conv2D(filters, (kernel_size, kernel_size), padding = 'same', activation= None)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x) 
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    return keras.layers.add([x,Input(input_shape)])
```

When I call this function from:

```
x = Input(shape = (6,264,264))
y = Conv2D(64, (7, 7), padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
y = MaxPooling2D((2,2))(y)
y = add_layer(y.shape, 3, 64, 3)
```

It gives following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_2: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5
```

When I remove the add_layer function and simply terminate the maxpooling to a dense layer, I get:

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

What could be the problem ? (Additionally my input has 50 np arrays of size (6,264,264)) i.e (50,6,264,264)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure that your line,

`x = Conv2D(filters, (kernel_size, kernel_size), padding = 'same', activation= None)(Input(input_shape))`

should be

`x = Conv2D(filters, (kernel_size, kernel_size), padding = 'same', activation= None)(Input(batch_shape=input_shape))`

By default the `ny_layer.shape` would add a batch size in the shape. However, for `Input(input_shape)` the first argument assumes the shape is without is batch size and adds another dimension to its output. This would explain  the origin of the extra dimension.